# how can i save both? 'threading class' and 'cmp'

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-multithreading

Excuse me for being so weak in English,

this is part of my code and i signed my problem in it:

==================

```
import threading
import time

exitFlag = 0

class process (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, processId = None , processName = None , initialTime = None , longTime = None ):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.processId = processId
        self.processName = processName
        self.initialTime = initialTime
        self.longTime = longTime

    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.processName
        print_time(self.processName, self.longTime, 5)
        print "Exiting " + self.processName

    def __str__(self):
        threading.Thread.__str__(self)
        return ('[' + str(self.initialTime) + ' ' + str(self.longTime) +']')


     ###############################
     ####### my problem area #######
     ###############################

    def __cmp__(self, other):



        if (self.initialTime > other.initialTime):
            return -1
        elif (self.initialTime < other.initialTime):
            return 1
        elif ((self.initialTime == other.initialTime)):
            if (self.longTime > other.longTime):
                return -1
            elif (self.longTime < other.longTime):
                return 1
            else :
                return 0
        else:
            return 0
     ###############################
     ####### my problem area #######
     ###############################

def print_time(threadName, delay, counter):
    while counter:
        if exitFlag:
            threadName.exit()
        time.sleep(delay)
        print "%s: %s" % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time()))
        counter -= 1
```

==================

i have problem with cmp i want use class threading and cmp both,
 my question is how can i save both in my process function

without threading, cmp worked! and whithout cmp, threading class worked!

==================

[whithout cmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meX4m.png)

[with cmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhOJX.png)

i need both, Thank You Friends

Comment: Please paste the full traceback in your question as text. In your image the most important part is missing. Also, your program is incomplete and does not start at all.